# Is it permissible to copy content from social networking sites?

Tags: seo, search-engines, copyright, twitter, google-plus

For a social page on Twitter or Google Plus that promotes tourism by renting a car in worldwide locations, will it count as a negative if we copy the content from an authoritative website?

For example, copying the exact lines from some website to promote our service in a particular location via that social page (that sends various backlinks to our website).

Comment: There's basic ethics at play if you're copying someone else's content period would you not say?

Comment: @GeoffJackson-zigojacko I don't know. How does google see this ?

Comment: Forget Google and consider the company that spend the time and money writing unique content that is likely copyrighted. How would you feel if someone ripped off your content to post across their social media channels? Either way, Google will take a dim view of copying content from someone else's website. Why can't you write your own content?

Comment: @GeoffJackson-zigojacko yeah..oka..so it takes in a negative view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is illegal to copy someone else's written work without their permission. You should also check the terms and conditions of the social network in question as well, because they may also have clauses where they retain some rights of what users post.

Furthermore, search engines typically frown upon content that is copied straight from other pages and rank them lower. However, aggregating small amounts of content from multiple sources is usually okay, provided you state where it's from.